# How can I stop LiteDB from adding the _type column automatically to my table?

Tags: c#, nosql, litedb

I have a LiteDB database I'm looking to use for a project. I'm trying to understand how I can stop the LiteDB database from adding a _type column when I do not want it to. Any advice on how this is controlled would be much appreciated.

Comment: Can you give an example of that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out, this was by using generic object type in the c# side rather than the custom type object. Using the custom object stops the _type column being added to the table.